# How do I create a linux C application with a console that I can connect to remotely

Tags: c, linux, console-application, remote-access, debian-stretch

I have a multi-threaded application written in
C that runs under Debian (Stretch).  One of the
threads is a simple console that supports several
commands to control the application.  Normally
this application is started automatically when
the system boots and runs in the background with
the console thread disabled.

I am looking for a way to "connect" to the application remotely so that I can use the console.
The connection could either be direct using a
port or I can just ssh to the box and then 
connect to the app.

During development I just run the app interactively
but would like the option to debug after it has
already started.

I thought something like netcat might work but it
seems to use TCP/IP ports whereas the console thread just connects to stdin/stdout.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: If your program works when you run it from the console interactively, and you don't want to undertake the (significant!) work to add a network text interface, you can start it during boot under a `screen` process.  `Screen` sets up a virtual terminal I/O environment, and you can connect your real terminal to it and talk to the program running there.  When you're done, you can disconnect from `screen` and the program won't know the difference.

Comment: Using a virtual terminal seems like the right way to go.  Either `tmux` or `screen` will serve that purpose.

Comment: Great ideas.  I will look into using one of those.  Also, thanks Basile for pointing out some great study topics.

Answer (score 1):

Read more about Linux programming, perhaps the old [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) (advanced linux programming) book (freely [downloadable](https://richard.esplins.org/static/downloads/linux_book.pdf)), or something newer. See also the [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) list. You want some [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

You need to learn more about [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets). See [sockets(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html); you might use Unix sockets, see [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) (or use [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) etc...), or even TCP/IP sockets, see [tcp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) (but then beware of hostile connections from the Internet). You need to use some multiplexing [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), such as [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). In simple cases, your user could just use [telnet](https://linux.die.net/man/1/telnet) to connect to your application (beware, there is no encryption involved; so you need to trust the connection, e.g. be on some internal LAN).

You could decide to add some web interface to your program (which then becomes a specialized web server, e.g. serving some `http://localhost:12345/` and similar URLs). Then use some HTTP *server* library, such as [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [libhttp](https://www.libhttp.org/). Of course that requires familiarity with Web technologies ([HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) & [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets), perhaps [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) and [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))). Then your user would use his/her browser to query the state of (or perhaps interact with) your application, or use some HTTP client command like [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/). I recommend that route, but it does require some work and familiarity with Web techniques.

You might also be interested by the [libssh](https://www.libssh.org/) library.

You could decide that your application becomes a service, and interface it to [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd).

PS. You should dedicate several days to *read* stuff before coding.